# how to get number of total core include thread

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel, cpu, lscpu

as all know lscpu give the info about number of CORE and number of Thread

```
lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                48
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-47
Thread(s) per core:    2
```

I am searching about command that can give the total as

( number of CORE ) X ( number of Thread ) = 96

so output will be as case above = 96 CPU

we can do as

```
 CORE=` nproc --all `
 THREAD=`  lscpu | grep -i Thread | awk '{print $NF}' `
```

and

```
echo "$(( $CORE*$THREAD ))"
```

but this isn't elegant way

or maybe other elegant approach ?

we try also this ( but not get the total 96 cores's )

```
num_cpus=$(nproc)
# echo $num_cpus
48
```

Comment: Does your `lscpu` output not give a `Core(s) per socket` and `Socket(s)` line?

Comment: The CPU(s) line reports the number of "logical" CPUs, so number of threads. I'd expect your system has 24 cores, probably 2 sockets of 12 cores each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `nproc` and the `CPU(s)` row in `lscpu` are the **total number of threads**.

So all you need to get the total number of threads is:

```
num_cpus=$(nproc)
```

Comment: nproc give only 48 and not 96!! so this isn't answer that I accepted

Comment: @yael, on my system, `nproc` also reports the number of threads. I would expect your system has 24 cores, 48 threads. Probably 2 x 12 core CPUs.

Comment: you can see from my question - CPU = 48 and Thread = 2 , so its 96